# Unexpected result with list append in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Here the goes,

```
list_of_list = [[]] * 10
list_of_list[0].append(1)
print(list_of_list)
```

There is a variable `list_of_list` which is a 10 element list containing empty list `[]`. So initially the list is `[[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]]`. So in the next line I have appended `1` to the first element of the variable `list_of_list`. So my expected result should be, `[[1],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]]`. But what I get is, `[[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1]]`.

So why is this happening? How can I get my achieved result?

Comment: It's a ten element list **containing the same list 10 times**. That is how `some_list * n` works where `n` is an `int`

Comment: you need `list_of_list = [[] for _ in range(10)]` This question has been asked several times on stack, see the previous answers linked above.

Comment: Whenever I search in StackOverflow, I don't find answer. But when I ask my question I find it already asked. (In the duplication section, I find the links). So, StackOverflow bot is smarter than me to find questions?

Comment: @MdAshrafulIslam it isn't bots. It is volunteer moderators. People who spend too much time on stack overflow they might be confused for bots :)